# Swift enum - switch statement matching associated values warning

Tags: swift

I have an enum declaring associated values in Swift, along with a method that is trying to get a value at a specific location in that entry:

```
enum myEnum {

    case entry0(Float=0.0, Float=0.0)

    ...

}

var entry0XValue: Float {
    switch self {
    case .entry0(let x, let _):
        return x
    default:
        return 0
    }
}
```

The code works, but the problem I'm having here is when I compile this, the compiler is giving this warning:

```
'let' pattern has no effect; sub-pattern didn't bind any variables
```

This is referring to the underscore in the case switches.  Is there any way to rewrite this to remove this warning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spell it like

```
case .entry0(let x, _):
```

Or like

```
case let .entry0(x, _):
```

which works more generally like:

```
case let .entry0(x, y):
```

Answer (score 0):

The effect of a `let <subpattern>` pattern is that it binds values to identifier patterns that appear in `<subpattern>`, when the pattern is matched against. For example, the `x` in `.entry0(let x, let _)` is bound to 0.0, when you match it against `MyEnum.entry0(0.0, 0.0)` in a switch statement. Another example: when you do `let (x, y) = (1, 2)`, the `x` and `y` are bound to `1` and `2` respectively. Note that in this case, `<subpattern>` is a tuple pattern, with identifier patterns inside it.

The `let` pattern `let _` "has no effect" because there are no identifier patterns in `<subpattern>` (the wildcard pattern, `_`, in this case). As a result, the `let` pattern will match if and only if `<subpattern>` matches, which means that you don't need `let` at all. You can just write `<subpattern>` directly.

```
case .entry0(let x, _):
```

This removes the warning.

Since the `.entry(...)` part is also a pattern (an enumeration case pattern), you can write that part as the `<subpattern>`:

```
case let .entry0(x, _):
```

For more info on the syntax of patterns, see the [Patterns](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Patterns.html#grammar_identifier-pattern) section of the language reference.